# maven slf4j error initializing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, slf4j

I've created a maven project using just

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

As soon as I try to run, I get an exception in StaticLoggerBinder related to sun.security.util.PolicyUtil.getKeyStore.

Eclipse never prints the actual exception, so I grabbed a screenshot and put it [here at dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ev0la7ih41xsq9i/Screen%20Shot%202016-11-02%20at%209.16.57%20AM.png?dl=0)

I pushed this up to [github](https://github.com/phomlish/logbackTest), please run in eclipse and you'll see the error.

thanks,
Paul

Comment: What is the exception message? Copy & paste the exact error message in your question, instead of asking people to get your project from Github and reproducing it for themselves. Did you also add a dependency to an implementation of the SLF4J API? Because `slf4j-api` is just the API, you also need an implementation of it (such as Logback or Log4J).

Comment: @Jesper I do apologize for not including the exception, but Eclipse does not print it anywhere I can grab it.  I did get a screenshot and added that to my question, and I did add all of my Maven logging dependencies.

Comment: Also, for what it is worth, the project I submitted to github is just a hello world that I created just to display this behavior.  No need to figure out my large project- it mostly consists of just a maven pom and a Main class.

Comment: @phomlish Hi I just wonder whether you found the solution for this. I am currently seeing exactly the same issue but my IDE is IntelliJ IDEA.